# Delphi REST and No mapping for the Unicode character exists

Tags: rest, delphi

I am trying to get PDF from via API but when in command restrequest.Execute happens then program crashes with error: No mapping for the Unicode character exists in the target multi-byte code page.
Does anybody have any idea what is wrong it?

Here is my code:

```
 RESTClientx := TRESTClient.Create(nil);
 restclientx.AcceptCharset  := 'uft-8, *;q=0.8';
 restclientx.ContentType    := 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
 restclientx.FallbackCharsetEncoding := 'raw';
 restclientx.BaseURL := 'https://ee.integration.dpd.eo.pl/ws-mapper-rest/parcelPrint_';

 RESTResponsex := TRESTResponse.Create(nil);
 RESTRequestx:= TRESTRequest.Create(nil);

 restrequestx.Client   := RESTClientx;

 RESTRequestx.Method   := rmpost;
 RESTRequestx.Params.Clear;
 RESTRequestx.ClearBody;

 RESTRequestx.Params.AddItem;
 RESTRequestx.Params.Items[0].Kind := pkHTTPHEADER;
 RESTRequestx.Params.Items[0].name := 'username';
 RESTRequestx.Params.Items[0].Value := 'xxxxxxx';
 RESTRequestx.Params.Items[0].Options := [poDoNotEncode];

 RESTRequestx.Params.AddItem;
 RESTRequestx.Params.Items[1].Kind := pkHTTPHEADER;
 RESTRequestx.Params.Items[1].name := 'password';
 RESTRequestx.Params.Items[1].Value := 'xxxxxxxx';
 RESTRequestx.Params.Items[1].Options := [poDoNotEncode];

 RESTRequestx.Params.AddItem;
 RESTRequestx.Params.Items[2].Kind := pkHTTPHEADER;
 RESTRequestx.Params.Items[2].name := 'parcels';
 RESTRequestx.Params.Items[2].Value := '01234567890';
 RESTRequestx.Params.Items[2].Options := [poDoNotEncode];

 RESTRequestx.Params.AddItem;
 RESTRequestx.Params.Items[3].Kind := pkHTTPHEADER;
 RESTRequestx.Params.Items[3].name := 'printType';
 RESTRequestx.Params.Items[3].Value := 'pdf';
 RESTRequestx.Params.Items[3].Options := [poDoNotEncode];

 restrequestx.Execute; <- this will cause error
```

.

Comment: `try..finally` blocks are not optional.

Comment: You should send the parameters as form fields, not headers.

Comment: @Olivier could explain little bit more. I am beginner with Rest. I tried put all parameters also directly to baseurl but I did not work. But if I use postman and use same baseurl then it it works in postman. So I assume that I do something wrong with Delphi and rest components